# Flagged a post twice

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've just been able to flag [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184837/s-there-aforge-net-algorithm-for-human-activity-recognition-2) twice within the space of 20 minutes (unintentionally, because it's been a long day and some of the things in my head have fallen out my ears). One of which is "Low Quality" and one of which is "Unclear what you're asking". Am wondering what the use of this is, or if this is even intentional?

Even if there is a valid reason for being able to flag twice, might be nice to have a warning that is displayed if you attempt to flag something more than once since there's no way of seeing whether you've flagged a question from the question itself (I realise you can see if you go into the flags list)

Comment: It looks like flags for closure are separate from the rest, but I can't be certain.